# Python - Exists a function that is called when an object does not implement a function?

Tags: python, oop, function

In Smalltalk there is a message `DoesNotUnderstand` that is called when an object does not understand a message (this is, when the object does not have the message sent implemented).

So, I like to know if in python there is a function that does the same thing.

In this example:

```
class MyObject:
    def __init__(self):
        print "MyObject created"

anObject = MyObject() # prints: MyObject created
anObject.DoSomething() # raise an Exception
```

So, can I add a method to `MyObject` so I can know when `DoSomething` is intented to be called?

PS: Sorry for my poor English.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a proposition for what you want to do:

```
class callee:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __call__(self):
        print self.name, "has been called"


class A:
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return callee(attr)

a = A()

a.DoSomething()
>>> DoSomething has been called
```

Comment: This is defiantly what I want! Thanks :)

Comment: I like it when someone is definitely defiant! (or is that "defiantly definite"?)  Whatever, SO saves the day again! :)

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for the `__getattr__` method. Have a look [here](http://pyref.infogami.com/__getattr__).

If you want "total control" of a class, look at the `__getattribute__` special method then ([here](http://pyref.infogami.com/__getattribute__)).

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at object.`__getattr__(self, name)`, or object.`__getattribute__(self, name)` for new-style classes? (see [Special method names, Python language reference](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names))

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why luc had the two separate classes.  You can do it all with one class, if you use a closure.  Like so:

```
class A(object):
    __ignored_attributes__ = set(["__str__"])

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        if __name__ in self.__ignored_attributes__:
            return None

        def fn():
            print name, "has been called with self =", self

        return fn

a = A()
a.DoSomething()
```

I added the bit about `__ignored_attributes__` because Python was looking up `__str__` in the class and that got a little messy.

Comment: two classes because it can be reused more easily. Imagine you want the same behavior for class B